# browser path for svn

Tags: svn

I have a test project in SVN repository.

- How can I check it with different browsers like (IE,Firefox) so I can test it? I mean what would be a path / URL in web browser for testing the project.
- Is there any other method to check a project in web browser?

Comment: What sort of testing are you talking about? Do you just want to view the svn tree in a browser?

Comment: Do you want to *view* the svn repository or do you wanna *test* your application in the browser?

Comment: yes i want to test my application in browser

any idea?

Comment: What kind of application? Written in what language?

Comment: Do you want to browse your svn repository, or are you asking how to test your *project* (which just happens to be in svn) in different browsers? These are *very* different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not offer browser access by default. You will have to install something like [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org) on your server.

Comment: but how can i test the project in browser... 
please tell me the way to check it in browser like ie, firefox

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't have a clue what you are asking now. I'll leave my answer in case it's useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) contains a standalone web server and a super [Subversion Repository Browser](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBrowser).

Answer (score 0):

There is a special apache module for svn (using webdav) which allows to do that. Take a look at [Configuring Apache for Subversion use](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5902186.html)

After that, you can enter into svn directory browser using:

**http://[your svn server]/svn/**

Answer (score 0):

you should add it in /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf something like:

```
 <Location /svn <!--here is the path from browser-->>
   ...
   SVNPath /usr/local/svn/ <!--physical path-->

   ...
 </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subversion (by itself) does not *deploy* or *build* your project. It *stores* it in a repository, which you can view with various tools or web pages depending on configuration. The other answers give you ways of using a web browser to do that.

But to test your *project* (which I'm assuming is a website), you need to deploy it to a web server. Then just point your browser (whichever one you choose) to that web server (and path / subdomain / etc.) to test.